# Herencia del destructor finalize

Tags: java

una duda respecto al destructor:

Tengo esto:

```
@Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        System.out.println("objeto fecha destruido");
    }
```

Me han recomendado que use el super.finalize() en la primera línea de la sobrecarga para evitar lagunas de memoria. No me han sabido explicar muy bien. Yo entiendo que cuando se va a destruir se ejecuta el destructor y se ejecuta finalize sin más, no creo yo que haga falta invocar al destructor en este caso de Object. Que esa es otra pregunta, si invoco en mi clase a super.finalize(), como sabe lo que tiene que destruir si el método que implementa Object  no sabe nada de mi clase.

Muchas gracias.

Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad tu no sabes cuando el Garbage collector va a destruir un objeto, en algún momento java determina que algún objeto no tiene referencias y lo destruye, cuando va a realizar esta acción es cuando llama al método finalize(). Lo que se recomienda es evitar construir objetos innecesariamente y además eliminar sus referencias cuando no sean útiles con esto aseguramos eliminar recursos.

con respecto a lo que comentas:

> Yo entiendo que cuando se va a destruir se ejecuta el destructor y se
>   ejecuta finalize sin más, no creo yo que haga falta invocar al
>   destructor en este caso de Object

En realidad no hace falta llamar este método, cuando el objeto se destruye se llama el método finalize().

> si invoco en mi clase a super.finalize(), como sabe lo que tiene que
>   destruir si el método que implementa Object no sabe nada de mi clase.

si sobreescribes el método `finalize()` en tus objectos, el Garbage collector llamará a estos métodos únicamente si los objetos son destruidos.

Este es un ejemplo que ayudará a entender el funcionamiento, suponiendo una clase:

```
class MyObject{

    String name;

    public MyObject(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("finalize() method was called for " + name);
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

Si creamos desde `main()` los objetos y llamamos el Garbage collector:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   MyObject object1 = new MyObject("Doctor");
   MyObject object2 = new MyObject("Cientifico");               

   System.gc();       
   System.out.println("temina main()");          

}
```

El método `finalize()` del objeto no es llamado por lo que tendremos como salida:

```
temina main()
```

---

En cambio si forzamos a destruir los objetos convirtiéndolos a null

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   MyObject object1 = new MyObject("Doctor");
   MyObject object2 = new MyObject("Cientifico");               

   object1 = null;
   object2 = null;

   System.gc();       
   System.out.println("temina main()");          

}
```

en este caso el método `finalize()` será llamado, tendremos como salida:

```
finalize() method was called for Cientifico
finalize() method was called for Doctor
temina main()
```

Comment: Y por qué pones super.finalize(); en la sobreescritura de finalize dentro de la clase MyObject? Es que lo que no entiendo es que si tu sobreescribes el destructor y este se ejecuta ya se está destruyendo el objeto, pero si llamas en la última línea a finalize de Object que parte de ese objeto está en el objeto derivado, no sé si me explico, cuando creamos un objeto de una subclase no lo hacemos también de la superclase, toda la memoria la tiene reservada con lo heredado el objeto derivado más lo que aporte este, si ya ponemos un finalize que sentido tiene llamar al de la clase base?